# Restful Wcf Service Issue at the consuming end

Tags: c#, wcf

I have developed a WCF service in VS2010.EVery thing is working fine.But when i have converted to restful service,not working at the consuming end(Console application).
Getting Error:The Address property on ChannelFactory.Endpoint was null.  The ChannelFactory's Endpoint must have a valid Address specified.
web.config settings of WCF restful service:

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DashBoardService.Service1Behavior"
        name="DashBoardService.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""  binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DashBoardService.IDashBoard" behaviorConfiguration="Web">
          <!--behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" ,behaviorConfiguration="Web"-->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
</services>
<behaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DashBoardService.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Dont know where am doing wrong.Please help me out of this.

Comment: Please post your code and how you're calling it (point out where the error is occurring).

Comment: I can't find any wrong with configuration file. Please put your code snippet.

Comment: address="" shall it not containg URL of your service?